# add hasMany relationship query laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

how do I hasMany relationship,
get the last 5 users, I try to use model and witch hasMany the relation appears empty.
I have already done many tests, I always have problems with the relationships when obtaining the last 5 users in each query

Query:

```
   $minute = Minute_Report::Query()->whereBetween('minutos.fecha', [$from, $to])
                ->join('clients', 'minutos.cliente', '=', 'clients.id')
                ->join('users as asesor', 'minutos.psiquico', '=', 'asesor.id')
                ->select(
                    'minutos.id',
                    'clients.code',
                    'clients.id as client',
                    \DB::raw("CONCAT(clients.firstname_c,clients.lastname_c) As client_full_name"),
                    \DB::raw("CONCAT(asesor.first_name,asesor.last_name) As asesor_full_name"),
                    'minutos.date2 As fechas',
                    'minutos.minutos',
                    \DB::raw('(CASE 
                WHEN minutos.motive = "MINUTOS GRATIS" THEN "GRATIS" 
                ELSE "PAGO" 
                END) AS status_lable'),
                    'minutos.motive',
                    'minutos.time_a',
    
                );
    
            $data = $minute->get();
```

result:

```
[
asesor_full_name: "Lucero /Liliana Fuentes"
client: 2079
client_full_name: "NICOLE MSALLS OCACIO"
code: 2078
fechas: "2021-01-01 09:40:44"
id: 64208
minutos: 27
motive: "MINUTOS GRATIS"
status_lable: "GRATIS"
time_a: "40"
]
```

success:

```
[
    asesor_full_name: "Lucero /Liliana Fuentes"
    client: 2079
    client_full_name: "NICOLE MSALLS OCACIO"
    code: 2078
    fechas: "2021-01-01 09:40:44"
    id: 64208
    minutos: 27
    motive: "MINUTOS GRATIS"
    status_lable: "GRATIS"
    time_a: "40"
    users[
        1,
        2,
        3,
        5
     ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i get it right but im gonna try to help.

did you define relationship in your Minute_Report model with User model? What is the relation column? should be like

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'xxx');
}
```

on your Minute_Report model. the 'xxx' refers to the relational column name on users table.

and after that you sould add "with('users')" on your query. like this:

```
$minute = Minute_Report::Query()->whereBetween('minutos.fecha', [$from, $to])
                ->join('clients', 'minutos.cliente', '=', 'clients.id')
                ->join('users as asesor', 'minutos.psiquico', '=', 'asesor.id')
                ->select(
                    'minutos.id',
                    'clients.code',
                    'clients.id as client',
                    \DB::raw("CONCAT(clients.firstname_c,clients.lastname_c) As client_full_name"),
                    \DB::raw("CONCAT(asesor.first_name,asesor.last_name) As asesor_full_name"),
                    'minutos.date2 As fechas',
                    'minutos.minutos',
                    \DB::raw('(CASE 
                WHEN minutos.motive = "MINUTOS GRATIS" THEN "GRATIS" 
                ELSE "PAGO" 
                END) AS status_lable'),
                    'minutos.motive',
                    'minutos.time_a',

            )->with('users');

        $data = $minute->get();
```

Comment: return empty :/